# SQLite query help for multiple options

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have an android app that is using a SQLite database to determine if certain 'achievements' are made.  I need a query that will return a cursor length of 4 if one of each 'season' is contained in a column.

So if I execute the query on a column '_id' as below:

```
_id:

yada
Autumn
yada
Summer
Summertime
yada
yada
Winter
Spring
```

it will return a cursor of 4 rows (thereby indicating that the achievement 'All Four Seasons' would be achieved.

Is this even possible with one query, or will I have to accomplish with multiple cursors and code in the app? I would like to use LIKE as not all entries will be exactly the same text (i.e. Summer or Summertime, but both should qualify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this in the where clause of the query, with and, like, or and parenthesis. Something like...

```
Cursor mC = mDb.query("season", null, "_id like '%summmer%' and "
    + "_id like '%winter%' and "
    + "_id like '%spring%' and "
    + "(_id like '%fall%' or _id like '%autumn%')",
    null, null, null, null);
```

After this you could have something like...

```
String [] seasons = new String[] {"spring", "summer", "fall", "autumn", "winter");
boolean fallExists = false;
int seasonCount = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
   if(i == 3 && fallExists) continue;
   mC.moveToFirst();
   do{
      if(mC.getString(ID_COLUMN).toLowerCase().contains(seasons[i])){
          seasonCount++;
          if(i == 2) fallExists = true;
      }
   } while ((mC.moveToNext()));
}

if(seasonCount == 4){
   //have a party
}
```

Comment: This accomplishes part of my goal, it returns rows containing the seasons.  However from my example it returns both Summer and Summertime rows, for a total of five rows in the cursor.  I need to somehow group the results so that only one record of each season is returned, regardless of the number of records containing a given season.

Comment: I'm just learning SQLite myself... but from what I can think... I don't believe that is possible. Return this row, but stop returning rows that equal this sub-part of the query... just sounds impossible but someone with better SQL knowledge should interject. What I'd do, personally, is check the row count and if it's 4 or greater, run some other qualification code on the results. Shouldn't be too hard to loop them and detect if at least one of each season exists. You could even have 4 results where there are two "Summers" so some qualification I think will have to be done.